# c++ makefile project how can I create a list of files with same basename plus suffix and same extension

Tags: c++, makefile, substitution

Sorry if the title is mis-leading, I could not phrase it quite right.

Basically I am using the RTI DDS generator to take *.idl files and generate *.cxx and *.h files.

So the generation is working, but I am trying to add a rule that cleans up all the generated files.

From a single *.idl file I get the following generated files:

running rtiddsgenerate on `test.idl` yields:

```
test.cxx
test.h
testPlugin.cxx
testPlugin.h
testSupport.cxx
testSupport.h
```

So I need a clean rule to remove these. I started making lists, here is the pseudo code that I have (not tested because I have to hand-copy this across to my email PC):

```
# Generate my lists of files
DDS_FILES = $(wildcard *.idl)
DDS_GEN_CXX = (DDS_FILES:.idl=.cxx)
DDS_GEN_H = (DDS_FILES:.idl=.h)

# Main rule - doesn't really do anything for the moment except call the DDS_GEN_CXX rule
run: $(DDS_GEN_CXX)

# rule for generating cxx files:
%.cxx: %.idl
    rtiddsgen.bat $<

# Rule to clean
clean:
    rm -f $(DDS_GEN_CXX) $(DDS_GEN_H)
```

So here you can see I have made file lists for the cxx and h files, but they only contain files with the same name as the .idl file (i.e. test.cxx and test.h), but not the files with test.cxx and test.h - where the suffix is `Plugin` and `Support`.

Two questions really:
 1. How can I create more variables that have these extra files e.g. `DDS_GEN_SUPPORT_CXX=?`, `DDS_GEN_PLUGIN_CXX=?`, `DDS_GEN_SUPPORT_H=?`, etc...
 2. Is there a better / clearer / more efficient way to do the same thing in make files?

Comment: you could probably use the `$(shell ...)` for the problem you have described

Comment: @0xtvarun can you expand that into an example and put it into an answer if you want and I'll vote it up if it works : )

Comment: I am not clear as to which files you need to be cleaned. are all the files that begin with `test` need to be cleaned?

Comment: Yes, I want to clean all the generated files. test.idl is effectively the source file all the other files are auto generated by rti-dds and are not source controlled so I want to be able to clean those from my system.

Comment: test.cxx
test.h
testPlugin.cxx
testPlugin.h
testSupport.cxx
testSupport.h
so all these files need to be cleaned?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$(shell ...)` to get the generated files. To get the files with the suffix Plugin and Support do the following

```
GEN_FILES=$(shell ls test* | grep -v '\.idl' | grep -E 'Plugin|Support')
```

Your clean rule will look like

```
clean:
     rm $(GEN_FILES)
```

Comment: I like it, my only reservation is: is it portable? i.e. same on windows and Linux? From what I understand the "shell" could be anything...

Comment: this might help https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html

Comment: In the interests of portability you could replace `$(shell ls test*` with `$(wildcard test*` and then replace the `grep`s with `$(filter-out ...` and `$(filter ...`.

Comment: @G.M. and 0xtvarun - after trying to implement this I notice an issue with this method (which might be fixable). We are explicitly using the word `test` in the pattern, yes its true in my example itstest.idl, but there could be any number of these with any name (test1.idl, something.idl, etc...) so I can't use this rule as it stands. Can it be modified? I am giving it a go on my PC, I am trying the "portable" version modded by G.M.

Answer (score 1):

A bit off-topic, but to make your `Makefile` robust it should use a rule with multiple outputs (only possible with pattern rules):

```
%.cxx %.h %Plugin.cxx %Plugin.h %Support.cxx %Support.h: %.idl
    rtiddsgen.bat $<
```

The above says that `rtiddsgen.bat` generates 5 files from an input `%.idl`.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I can't quite get my head around this though - won't it try to run rtiddsgen.bat multiple times (once for each output)?

Comment: Not in this case since this is a `pattern` rule (as opposed to `static`).

Comment: @G.M. hmm, I take you're word for it, I just read the blurb on pattern rule, but I don't quite get why it does this only once - is it because it only uses the first match?

Comment: Not quite.  All targets specified are treated equally.  It's simply that make will remember that the rule has already been invoked and also the names of the targets generated.  Hence, if a later request is made for any of the targets it knows (or *assumes* might be a better word) that it doesn't have to re-run the command.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've solved this completely yet but, in one comment you state...

> there could be any number of these with any name (test1.idl,
> something.idl, etc...) so I can't use this rule as it stands

You can probably address this with the use of make's [`foreach`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function) builtin function.

```
# Start with the list of .idl files in the current directory.
#
DDS_FILES := $(wildcard *.idl)

# Strip the .idl extension from the .idl files.
#
DDS_FILES_BASES := $(patsubst %.idl,%,$(DDS_FILES))

# Specify the list of suffixes that will be used by rtiddsgen.bat.  Depending on
# the specifics of the problem it may be desirable to split this into multiple
# variables: e.g. one for .h files and one for .cxx files.  The principle
# remains the same regardless.
#
DDS_FILES_SUFFIXES := .h .cxx Plugin.h Plugin.cxx Support.h Support.cxx

# idl_generated_files
#
# Simple function/macro which, given the base name of an idl file will generate
# the names of generated files.
#
define idl_generated_files =
  $(foreach suffix,$(DDS_FILES_SUFFIXES),$(1)$(suffix))
endef

# Now use idl_generated_files in conjunction with `foreach' to generate the
# names of all files generated by rtiddsgen.bat for all .idl files.
#
DDS_FILES_GENERATED := $(foreach idl_file,$(DDS_FILES_BASES), \
                         $(call idl_generated_files,$(idl_file)) \
                       )

# This pattern rule tells make how to build any of the generated files derived
# from a .idl file.  We use idl_generated_files with a parameter of `%' to
# create the target patterns for us.
#
$(call idl_generated_files,%): %.idl
    rtiddsgen.bat $<

# Rule to clean
clean:
    -rm -f $(DDS_FILES_GENERATED)

# Simple target for printing the value of a variable.  Useful for testing.
#
print-%:
    @printf '[$*] = [$($*)]\n'
```

By way of some simple testing I created two files in a directory -- `test_a.idl` and `test_b.idl`.  A quick check of the generated file names gives...

> ps1 > make print-DDS_FILES_GENERATED
>
> [DDS_FILES_GENERATED] = [   test_b.h test_b.cxx test_bPlugin.h test_bPlugin.cxx test_bSupport.h
> test_bSupport.cxx     test_a.h test_a.cxx test_aPlugin.h
> test_aPlugin.cxx test_aSupport.h test_aSupport.cxx ]